# I have created a commandlist but when I run ffmpeg() it says not defined. Does the ffmpeg() needs the commandlist nested or am I missing something?

Tags: ffmpeg

#/ *I have ommited the first half of the code*/

```
def buildFFmpeg():
        commandlist = [
            "ffmpeg",
            "-i",
            inputdic[1],
            "-c:v",
            inputdic[4],
            "-preset",
            inputdic[3],
            "-crf",
            inputdic[2],
            "-q:v",
            inputdic[6],
            "-c:a",
            inputdic[5],
            "-b:a",
            inputdic[7],
            "output.mkv"        
            ]
    
    return commandlist
    
    def runFFmpeg(commandlist):

            print(commandlist)               

            if subprocess.run(commandlist).returncode == 0:

                    print ("FFmpeg Script Ran Successfully")

            else:
                    print ("There was an error running your FFmpeg script")
                    
                
    print('Press 1 to start to encoding or 2 to stop this process')

    start = input('Press to start: ')

    x = int(start)

    if x == 1:
        runFFmpeg(buildFFmpeg())

    else:
         exit()
```

so with the changes of {runFFmpeg()} -- {runFFmpeg(buildFFmpeg())} in line 58 and def {runFFmpeg():} -- {def runFFmpeg(commandlist):} in line45 the code runs successfully. But I would like to understand as to how defining the {def runFFmpeg(commandlist):} and executing {runFFmpeg(buildFFmpeg())} makes the code work.

Comment: You need to put "ffmpeg" in quotes since it is the name of the executable and not a Python variable

Comment: Thank you for your reply but there are two error in lines.
Error 47 - runFFmpeg print(command) :NameError: name 'command' is not defined.
Error 58 - <module>runFFmpeg(). This two

Comment: it seems like the variable you want is commandlist not command.

Comment: yeah I took your suggestion but the same error pops up. Would it be possible for you to run the code successfully with an input or if you can change the code to fit in this case. I am very new at python so any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: update the question with the latest copy of the code and the current error message. thanks

Comment: so with the changes of {runFFmpeg()} -- {runFFmpeg(buildFFmpeg())} in line 58 and def {runFFmpeg():} -- {def runFFmpeg(commandlist):} in line45 the code runs successfully. But I would like to understand as to how defining the {def runFFmpeg(commandlist):} and executing {runFFmpeg(buildFFmpeg())} makes the code work.

Comment: your code as printed would never work, because python is very sensitive to indentation.  but if you think about the buildFFmpeg() call that returns a list.  even though that list is known as commandlist inside buildFFmpeg()  outside it is just a list.  You pass that list into a runFFmpeg() function which takes that list and assigns it to a variable, which happens to also be called commandlist.   While you can embed functions inside functions in python, you cannot do so after a return statement.  it is important to have accurate indentation when discussing python code.

Comment: Thank you for that explanation and also for your patience in letting me understand it all.